# use name of a directory as a variable

Tags: php, user-interface

I have a file thats displayed on a user page in an iframe, but I need the content in this iframe to get the name of the users folder as a variable.

to better explain, I have /logins/users/foo/foo.php
foo.php embeds a universal file all user pages use called skin.php in /logins/skins/skin.php
the universal page changes the skin it displays based on a variable $user
i need $user to be whatever the folder name is that the page being viewed is in.

is there any way to do this? I can do it on the user page itself using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/index.css" />
<?php
    $path = DIRNAME($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $position = STRRPOS($path,'/') + 1;
    $user= SUBSTR($path,$position);
    $root="/";

include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/menu/nav.php');

echo '<iframe src="/logins/skin/index.php?user=$user"/>'
?>
```

is there anyway to pass that variable to the iframed content?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can build a query string parameter..

```
echo "<iframe src="http://your/path/to/iframe.php?user=$user"/>
```

Comment: says undefined variable, am I doing something wrong?
echo '<iframe src="/logins/skin/index.php?user=$user"/>'

Comment: is $user defined at that stage? I'm just going off the code segment you posted..maybe post full listing?

Comment: @user2386278 - you will have to define $user as described in your question before echoing out iframe.

Comment: @DoryZidon I've edited my original post with the full code, the variable $user is defined